# emacs startup 'Symbol's function definition is void: debian-startup'

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, debian

I'm getting an error on emacs startup that is causing it to not load the filenames I give it on the command line.  I don't see anything in my ~.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el that says anything about 'debian-startup'.  What is this message?  How do I make it go away?  If it goes away will I be able to open a file directly from the commandline like [ emacs project.clj ]?  I don't know if it matters, but its GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 running on an Ubuntu Saucy Server VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on your command line that starts Emacs: `--debug-init`. Then, when the error is raised you will be put into the debugger, where you can see a backtrace showing what tried to invoke the undefined function, etc.

(It sounds like there might be something is in the Debian site init file that is causing the problem. You might also want to ask the Debian people directly. ;-))

Comment: Hmmm.  --debug-init doesn't seem to do anything different.  It looks like I do have to find out who the Debian people are.

Comment: That means that no error is raised when processing your init file.  What happens if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and mention the same files on the command line? What happens if you do not use `-Q` (as before) but you do not specify any files on the command line?

Comment: When I use `emacs -Q bob.txt`, the file opens without issue.  When I `emacs bob.txt` I see the "Symbol's function void" complaint.  When I `emacs` without any filename I see the "Symbol's function void" complaint.  I've found a file called `/usr/share/emacs-snapshot/site-lisp/debian-startup.el` that could be at the source of the problem, but not really knowing emacs startup, nor why my VM is working from some snapshot of emacs, the file itself looks fine to me.

Comment: OK, then you know that the problem is not in your init file and has nothing to do with mentioning files on the command line. The problem is presumably with either `default.el` or `site-start.el`. See the Emacs manual, node [`Init File`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). Contact Debian/Ubuntu (you might want to pose the question on the Ubuntu S.E. site).

Answer (score 8):

Last entry in this thread was 1.5yrs ago, but the problem still exists. I think I have found its source. Today I installed Ubuntu 15 and added Emacs to it. Starting Emacs produced the error about the function `debian-startup` not being defined. I didn't find much about this on the web, though I don't understand why not -- surely many, many people use Emacs on Ubuntu. And maybe the problem isn't even restricted to Ubuntu, but occurs in any Debian Linux.

The problem turned out to be that `debian-startup.el` is found in (for Emacs.24.5, e.g.) `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/site-lisp`, one of the early entries in `load-path`. There, it is a link to `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/debian-startup.el`. That file exists and defines the function `debian-startup`. ***However***, an empty file `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/site-lisp/debian-startup.elc` was installed at the same time as the link. This file should not exist -- it is rarely appropriate to byte-compile any kind of init file. In this case, the empty compiled file is being loaded in place of the real Lisp file, so of course `debian-startup` is not defined. Deleting the `.elc` file solves the problem. (Note that this would have to be done separately for each version of Emacs in use.)

(It seems very strange that this problem could still be in the Emacs installation packages after all this time? Maybe I am missing something.)

Comment: Brilliant answer! Deleting the mentioned file has successfully resolved the issue. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Comment: This problem still exists 3 years later??? WTF?! But delighted my response was helpful.

Comment: The same issue persists on emacs 25.2 and this fix solves this as well.